# Maven vaadin war can't find a properties file when deployed

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, vaadin, war

I've a Vaadin application which has a few configuration properties in `./src/main/resources/VAADIN/myfile.properties`. I debug this application on a jetty while developing and test the d-version on a tomcat server via the maven tomcat plugin.

```
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
```

Goals:

- While developing: `jetty:run`
- D-version: `tomcat7:run`

This works great.

The problem ist, that the app won't run if I package the whole thing via the `package` goal and deploy the resulting war to the q-system (also a Tomcat 7). I open up the deployed application and it immediately throws an MissingResourceException coming from the line where the above mentioned properties file is needed for the first time.

---

Additional information:

- I've also tried to do a manual export out of Eclipse - same results
- The resources are correctly placed beneath "classes"

  This screenshot shows the content of `./WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/` *of the war-file*:

  [image: content of the war file]

  The Login_application.properties is the mentioned file.
- The line throwing the exception looks like this:

  `final ResourceBundle aR = ResourceBundle.getBundle("VAADIN.Login_Application", loc, cl);`
- Also desperately tried:

  `final ResourceBundle aR = ResourceBundle.getBundle("VAADIN.Login_Application");`

  with the same results of course.

*Many thanks :)*

Comment: How do you access the missing file in code?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich I've edited the question. Do you need any further information?

Comment: Oh my gosh... did I just setup this question because of a typo? O.o Login_Application (Java code) vs. Login_application (actual filename). Strange that it still works while debugging though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a typo. Sorry for the waste of time.

I've renamed the file to "Login_**A**pplication.properties" instead of "Login_**a**pplication.properties" and everything works fine. Still strange that it worked in the jetty and tomcat while developing.

Comment: Are you perhaps developing on windows and deploying on unix/linux?

Comment: @Morfic Good idea (!) but unfortunately not.